# Selecting solutions that evaluate to positive

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, matrix

How to extract symbolic outputs of `Solve` that evaluate to positive at given values of parameters? 
For example, if `sol = {x, y} /.Solve` outputs `{{a, a}, {b, a}, {a, b}, {b, b}}` and only `{a, a}` has both elements positive at `{a -> 1, b -> -1}`, then the desired output is `{a,a}`.

My attempted code (simple example)

```
Clear[sol, solindex, a, b]
sol = {x, y} /. 
  Solve[{(x - a)*(x - b) == 0, (y - ay)*(y - by) == 0}, {x, y}]
solindex = 
 Boole[Positive[(sol /. {a -> 1, b -> -1,ay->2,by->-2})[[All, 2]]]]*
  Boole[Positive[(sol /. {a -> 1, b -> -1,ay->2,by->-2})[[All, 1]]]]
 Extract[sol, solindex]
```

outputs `Symbol`, or in the more complicated real problem I am trying to solve, gives the error `Extract: position specification... not applicable`.

Based on answers to list manipulation questions, I also tried

```
Pick[sol, (# /. {a -> 1, b -> -1}) & > 0]
Select[sol, (# /. {a -> 1, b -> -1}) > 0 &]
solindex2 = 
 Positive[{Boole[Positive[(sol /. {a -> 1, b -> -1})[[All, 2]]]]*
Boole[Positive[(sol /. {a -> 1, b -> -1})[[All, 1]]]]}]
Extract[sol, solindex2]
```

and get an error or empty output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure whether I got your point, but given:

```
out = sol /. {a -> 1, b -> -1, ay -> 2, by -> -2}
```

then taking elements with second part positive is:

```
Select[sol /. {a -> 1, b -> -1, ay -> 2, by -> -2}, Last[#] > 0 &]
(* {{1, 2}, {-1, 2}} *)
```

Extracting elements with both parts positive, e.g.

```
Pick[out, And @@@ (Positive /@ out)]
(* {{1, 2}} *)
```

Comment: A small modification to your answer: `Clear[sol, out, a, b, ay, by]
sol = {x, y} /. 
  Solve[{(x - a)*(x - b) == 0, (y - ay)*(y - by) == 0}, {x, y}]
out = sol /. {a -> 1, b -> -1, ay -> 2, by -> -2};
Pick[sol, And @@@ (Positive /@ out)]` does what I want: picks the solution where both elements evaluate to positive.